# demonstration of combinatorial analysis

Tags: combinatorics

How can i demonstrate that $\langle x \rangle_n$ is always divisible by $n!$ ? i.e. that this division always gives me an integer number.
$$\frac{\langle x \rangle_n}{n!}$$
where $\langle x \rangle_n$ = $x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)$

EDIT: $\forall x,n$ integers and $\ge1$

Comment: You can't, since it's false if, say, $x=1/2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think Juan probably meant that $x$ and $n$ are integers (the claim is meaningless otherwise): if you have an issue with that not being explicitly stated, it would have been more constructive to simply say that. To Juan: think about binomial coefficients, what you have are exactly the products that appear in those.

Comment: @NickPavlov I updated correctly the text. But how can i demonstrate that this division always gives me an integer number? Thank you

Comment: @Nick, the claim is not meaningless if $x=1/2$; it is quite meaningful, but false. And when I have an issue with the statement of a question, in general I would rather have OP think about what's missing, than try to read OP's mind. Each to his/her own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \frac{\langle x \rangle_n}{n!}= \dfrac {x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)}{n!}=\dfrac {(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!n!}=\dfrac {(x+n-1)!}{((x+n-1)-n)!n!}$$

$$=\displaystyle {x+n-1 \choose n}$$

An easier way to remember this is: The product of $n$ consecutive positive integers is always divisible by $n!$